# Regex - alphabetical with hyphen

Tags: regex

I would like to have a regular expression that checks if string of up to 14 alpha-numeric chars. can include hyphen, not at the beginning or end.

This what I have so far:

```
var patt = new RegExp("^([a-zA-Z0-9]+(-[a-zA-Z0-9])*){1,14}$");
```

But it's not working - http://jsfiddle.net/u6cWs/1/

Any idea?

Comment: change your regex to like this and try once `/^([a-zA-Z0-9]+([a-zA-Z0-9- ]){1,14})$/`

Comment: can it have more than one hyphen? is it valid `a-b-c`?

Comment: @Ulugbek Umirov - yes

Comment: @cheziHoyzer Did one of the answers work, or are you still wrestling with it? Please let us know. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use positive lookahead (count number of alpha-numeric chars with optional hyphen).

If only single hyphen is allowed:

```
^(?=([a-zA-Z0-9]-?){1,14}$)[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/eK7yS9)**

If multiple hyphens are allowed:

```
^(?=([a-zA-Z0-9]-?){1,14}$)[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/nJ7iV1)**

Additional option:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9](?:-?[a-zA-Z0-9]){0,13}$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/mG2cW1)**

Comment: +1 --- not my approach, but it works and the answer is well explained. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution that is faster because it does not use lookaheads:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9](?:[-A-Za-z0-9]{0,12}[A-Za-z0-9])?$
```

See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/qM8jD1).

**How does it work?**

1. Like your original pattern, this regex is anchored between `^` and `$`, enforcing our limit on the number of characters.
2. The first character has to be a letter or digit.
3. The rest of the string, included in a `(?:` non-capturing group, is made optional by the `?` at the end. This rest of the string, if it is there (more than one character), must end with a letter or digit. In the middle, you can have between 0 and 12 letters, digits or hyphens.

**Optionally**

If you want your regex to be a little shorter, turn on the case-insensitive option, and remove either the lower-case chars or the upper-case ones, for instance:

```
^[a-z0-9](?:[-a-z0-9]{0,12}[a-z0-9])?$
```

Comment: That's a nice solution. You need to add optional hyphen before the last char.

Comment: Why not `^(?!-)[a-z0-9-]{0,13}[a-z0-9]$` =)

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov `That's a nice solution.` Thank you, so is yours. :) `You need to add optional hyphen before the last char` Don't think so, see [demo](http://regex101.com/r/qM8jD1)

Comment: @zx81 `123456789-123-4` doesn't match, while it should.

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov It doesn't match because it's 15 chars. `123456789-12-4` matches.

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov How do you figure? That's 15 characters.

Comment: @hwnd Nice one! A bit harder to explain. :)

Comment: @zx81 As I understand we shouldn't count hyphens, do we?

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov Ha this is where we understood it differently. I'm assuming a 14 max width.

Answer (score 0):

Use two regexes for simplicity and readability.

First check that it matches this:

```
/^[A-Za-z0-9-]{1,14}$/
```

then check that it does NOT match this:

```
/^-|-$/
```